# Why does a PDF plot in ggplot2 not show title nor labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a simple step plot using ggplot2. If I switch the file type from PNG to PDF the plot does not show labels, ticks nor a title or a legend. What I'm doing wrong?

Data:

```
plotData <- structure(list(iteration = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), time = c(0L, 10L, 
20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 0L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 
40L, 50L, 60L, 70L), routes = c(6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("iteration", 
"time", "routes"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L
))
```

Code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    x_axis_breaks <- seq(10, 100, by = 10)

    png(file="plot.png",width=1280, height=1280)
    ## pdf(file="plot.pdf",width=6,height=6)
    plot <- ggplot(plotData) + geom_step(data=plotData, size = 5, 
         mapping=aes(x=time,    
         y=routes, group=iteration, colour=factor(iteration)), direction="vh")
    plot <- plot + scale_x_discrete(breaks=x_axis_breaks, name="time") + 
                   scale_y_discrete(name="#routes");
    plot <- plot + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(size=36,face="bold"), 
                        axis.text.y=theme_text(size=36,face="bold")) +
                        scale_colour_hue(name="iteration")
    plot <- plot + opts(legend.title=theme_text(size=36,face="bold"), 
                        legend.text=theme_text(size=36,face="bold"))
    plot <- plot + opts(axis.title.x=theme_text(size=36,face="bold"),
                        axis.title.y=theme_text(size=36,face="bold"))
    plot <- plot + opts(title="network lifetime", 
             plot.title=theme_text(size=36, face="bold"))
    print(plot)
    dev.off()
```

The problem occurs if I'm switching from 'png...' to 'pdf'. The data itself is plotted fine. Maybe I'm just missing some information on generating PDF plots in ggplot2?

Comment: I see that you have `dev.off()` here (although it didn't make it into your code block), but the symptoms here sound suspiciously like forgetting to call `dev.off()` ...

Comment: Cleaned up your code, but didn't change its functionality.  Works for me on Ubuntu 10.04 with R-devel.  Can you give results of `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: Works for me, too, on OSX and R 2.15.1. You might try `ggsave("plot.png")`.

Comment: @DrewSteen sorry, I saw your comment right after posting my answer. :-/

Comment: I had the same issue but it was only when viewing with Adobe Acrobat. Opening the pdf in Chrome worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is due to font embedding.

R does not embed fonts by default and this causes issues that you have described on some PDF readers. Usually you will have no problems with such figures on Adobe Reader that ships with a lot of fonts, while other readers might not come with a lot of fonts (commercial ones in particular) and typically they try to substitute the missing fonts with the closest ones. Sometimes this will fail and you don't see any fonts. i often have this problem with Evince on Ubuntu, not only with R plots but any other PDF that where fonts are not embedded.

On Ubuntu you can check status of the fonts of a pdf file with `pdffonts file.pdf`.

Some solutions:
- use `cairo_pdf` device when producing pdf in R, usually this does the trick
- use `extrafont` package to embed the desired font (font has to be available on your OS), see [here](https://github.com/wch/extrafont) for details

Answer (score 1):

In combination with ggplot you should use `ggsave()` for saving images:

```
ggsave( "plot.png", plot )
ggsave( "plot.pdf", plot )
...
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `ggsave`, although under the hood it uses `png` and `dev.off` so this should work.